# fatal error: concurrent map read and map write

Tags: go

```
fatal error: concurrent map read and map write

goroutine 5065809 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x6b4281, 0x21)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95 fp=0xc420c05670 
sp=0xc420c05650
runtime.mapaccess1_faststr(0x65ea20, 0xc420015020, 0xc42178ea8e, 0x16, 
0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap_fast.go:201 +0x4f3 
fp=0xc420c056d0 sp=0xc420c05670
collider.(*Collider).httpHandler(0xc420013120, 0x7c4dc0, 0xc4209dcdd0, 
0xc420a954a0)
        /home/ec2-user/goWorkspace/src/collider/collider.go:176 +0x7dd 
fp=0xc420c05c48 sp=0xc420c056d0
```

and the code is

```
    query := r.URL.Query()
    if(query["q"] == nil){
        c.httpError("must have a question",w)
        return
    }
    m := query["q"][0]       //this is line 176
```

It happens about once per day and after it happens the whole http server is down. I don't know if the http get do some concurrent writes in map.
How to solve this?

Comment: The error message is incomplete. It also contains a trace to the map write. You need to synchronize both functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a global variable for the map. Global variables are accessible by every request. With bad luck two requests try to access the same map at the same time, hence your error.

The easiest fix would be to use a `Map` from the package `sync`. But this could be more of a workaround according to your use case. But this slows down your program.

An alternative would be to define the map inside the handler if you only need it there.

If you could post more of your file, it would be easier to give a better answer.